# how to select query in codeigniter and display it in ionic?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, ionic-framework

I dont know if my code for select query in codeigniter is right I' ve been getting this result from my console:

[screencap of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EvU8.png)

home.php ( codeigniter - controller )

```
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

if (isset($postdata))
{
    $post = json_decode($postdata);

    echo json_encode($this->user_model->select());

}
```

user_model.php ( model - codeigniter )

```
 public function select(){

     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('usersrecipes');

     $q = $this->db->get();
     return $q->result();
    }
```

RecipeService.js (ionic)

```
getrecipe: function(thisrecipe){


        $http.post('http://localhost/admin-recipick/home/ajaxSelectrecipe', thisrecipe).then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }, function(err){
             console.error('ERR', err);
        });
    }
```

controllers.js (ionic)

```
   var s =  UserRecipeList.getrecipe();
      console.log(s)
```

Comment: Could you copy paste the console input into this question please. It would make it easier to answer.

Comment: thats the only code that I have I dont know how to display the data from database to ionic. please help me @Jean-BernardPellerin

Comment: What do you need exactly?, if you want to get only the data from userecipes?..remember specif the content...ei:

 $json json_encode($this->user_model->select(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
echo $json;

Comment: I need all the data in usersrecipes and display it in ionic

Answer (score 0):

controller for codeigniter

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);      
if (isset($params['name']))
{
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $result = $this->user_model->select();

 if ($result==TRUE) {
  $data['message']  = $result;

    } else {

  $data['message'] = 'error';        
}
 echo json_encode($data);
```

model for codeigniter

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('usersrecipes');
$query = $this->db->get();
 $result = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: what should I put in my ionic controller to view the data sir Nadesh?